# How to share files between users with username or email

Tags: django, postgresql

I have a small django app where users can upload files. I want users to be able to send files to others by name or email. How can I do that?
Thanks in advance

my exist project--> https://github.com/asimancalil/File_Sharing_DjangoApp

Comment: What did you try at the moment ?

Comment: I'm just researching for now.if you have any idea for that please share with me

Comment: You mean you're searching a library to do it or you will create it all by yourself ?

Comment: I need to do it in the simplest way.I have no idea for that